# Can't properly load JSON into DOM because of this keyword

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, module, mustache

I'm trying to load JSON via javascript modular pattern. 
I want 3 people on JSON file, get loaded into DOM.
I believe after binding this into `loadingData` function, it points to the wrong object

Here is my code

```
(function() {

    var people = {
        people: [],

        init: function() {
                this.cacheDom();
                this.bindEvents();
                this.render();
        },

        cacheDom: function () {
            this.$el = document.querySelector('#peopleModule');
            this.$button = this.$el.querySelector('button');
            this.$input = this.$el.querySelector('input');
            this.$ul = this.$el.querySelector('ul');
            this.template = this.$el.querySelector('#people-template').innerHTML;
        },

        bindEvents: function() {
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', this.loadingData.bind(this));

        },

        render: function() {
            var data = {
                people: this.people
            };
            this.$ul.innerHTML = Mustache.render(this.template, data);
        },

        loadingData: function() {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
                url = 'data/data.json',
                _self = this,
                result;
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    _self.people = result.people;
                }
            };
            xhr.open('GET', url, true);
            xhr.send();

        }
    };

    people.init();

})();
```

here is my JSON

```
{
    "people": [
        {
            "name" : "Cameron"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Alex"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Sara"
        }
    ]   
}
```

And here is my HTML

```
<div id="peopleModule">
        <h1>People</h1>
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
            <button id="addPerson">Add Person</button>          
        </div>
        <ul id="people">
            <script id="people-template" type="text/template">
                {{#people}}
                <li>
                    <span>{{name}}</span>
                    <del>X</del>
                </li>
                {{/people}}
            </script>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Because you are just calling your functions, rather than using `new` to create object instances from them, `this` isn't representing those instances. `people` shouldn't be declared as an object literal, it should be declared as `function People` and then you would call it with `let peopleObj = new People()`. Then `peopleObj` would reference the object instance that was created and `this` would also refer to that within the running code.

Comment: if I remove loadingData object and just use sample data like people = ['1', '2', '3'] it works also if I run every other functions as callback function for loadingData it also load data from JSON, but I dont like callback solution

Comment: when I put an alert in loadingData function it executes, why are saying this?

Comment: I'm not saying your functions won't execute. I'm saying that they way you are invoking your functions are causing `this` not to bind the way you want it to. `this` is meant to be used within constructor functions (functions that are invoked with the `new` keyword).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had put `render()` function in a wrong place

It didnt has to do with `this` keyword

```
(function() {

    var people = {
        people: [],

        init: function() {
                this.cacheDom();
                this.bindEvents();
        },

        cacheDom: function () {
            this.$el = document.querySelector('#peopleModule');
            this.$button = this.$el.querySelector('button');
            this.$input = this.$el.querySelector('input');
            this.$ul = this.$el.querySelector('ul');
            this.template = this.$el.querySelector('#people-template').innerHTML;
        },

        bindEvents: function() {
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', this.loadingData.bind(this));

        },

        render: function() {
            var data = {
                people: this.people
            };
            this.$ul.innerHTML = Mustache.render(this.template, data);
        },

        loadingData: function() {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
                url = 'data/data.json',
                _self = this,
                result;
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    _self.people = result.people;
                    _self.render();
                }
            };
            xhr.open('GET', url, true);
            xhr.send();

        }
    };

    people.init();

})();
```